# accessing class data on window function typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, youtube-api

I am building an application with Angular 2 and I'm also using the YouTube IFrame API.

The Youtube API requires me to declare some functions to the global object, so this is my code:

```
export class MyClass {

  someData: any;

  constructor( ... ) {
    ...
  }

  loadAPI(){
    (window as any).onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
      buildPlayer();
    }

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    console.log('API loaded');
  }

}
```

It works fine, then, outside of the class I have this:

```
function buildPlayer(){
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
  console.log('youtube iframe api ready!');
}

function onPlayerReady(event){
  // HERE IS MY PROBLEM
  // I want to manipulate "someData" in these functions
}

function onPlayerStateChange(status){
  // HERE IS MY PROBLEM
}
```

I want to manipulate some data that comes from MyClass (that is retreiving it from the database) inside these functions, but when I try to access it with "this.data" it says it's undefined. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer with some help with the portuguese version of stackoverflow.
What I had to do is declare the variable outside of the class, just as the functions. So it's like this:

```
let someData: any;

export class MyClass {    

    someData: any; // after manipulate the data in here, I can just
                   // set it like this: someData = this.someData;  

    constructor() {

    }

    loadAPI(){
    (window as any).onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
      buildPlayer();
    }

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    console.log('API loaded');
    }
} 

function buildPlayer(){
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
  console.log('youtube iframe api ready!');
}

function onPlayerReady(event){
    // I can manipulate it here
    console.log(someData);   
}

function onPlayerStateChange(status){
    // I can manipulate it here
    console.log(someData);        
}
```

It was a simple thing and I was thinking too complicated. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about using Angular 2, but I would think that it needs to be "**event.data**".

Comment: Actually, if I use "event.data", I'm accessing the "YT player" data. That's not what I want. Let's say I have an attribute in my class called "id" and I want to use this id in those functions, how do I access it?

Comment: If the data you are using is info related to youtube channel video's, there are accompanying scripts for the player. Else if it is outside stuff that you just want to run at the same time, have a function call inside the youtube function to do what you are wanting.

Comment: I editted the question to specify better what I want.

Comment: If it is returning "undefined", there is a good possibility that the code has a fault somewhere ( or your info is not returning ). UNDEFINED can cover many problems in the code. I sagest to slowly check all your code for any errors.

Comment: I don't think you get it. The problem here is not a typo or an error. The problem is that the functions placed out of the class are in the window scope and they get undefined value when I try to access the class' data.

Comment: You are trying to wrap a wrapper. Set your class as stand alone and make it public. If that still don't work, check the code for errors. P.S. "undefined" does not have to mean that you have a typo.